# Featured tab at 0?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

[image]

I saw this recently. Why 0 featured questions, when clearly there are?

Comment: It's counting correctly on the *featured* tab for tags, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=featured, but http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured is broken indeed.

Comment: Very interesting. I could reproduce this a few seconds ago, but now I can't. Instant fix?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I just saw it both with the tab active and inactive, now it's counting correctly when the tab is active. (Edit) it's again showing 0 with the tab active.

Comment: It's oscillating indeed. Let's wait and see :)

Comment: The feature tab doesn't even show up for me when I am on the front page.  Only when I am on `/questions` or filtering by tag.

Comment: @psubsee2003 so the tabs you see are interesting, hot, week and month? Perhaps a (broken) userscript?

Comment: @Stijn correct, but no user script.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: shouldn't this be tagged featured since it is about the featured tab? :P

Comment: Shows 0 again today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an occasional and unfortunate side effect of the mechanisms of caching that we use to keep this site functioning and speedy despite getting tens of millions of visitors per month.

Sometimes certain queries (such as the one to count the featured questions) take a little longer than expected and get cached in a bad state for a period of time. Although infrequent, it does create odd scenarios such as this.

Unfortunately, to guarantee the *correct* number at all times we'd have to ensure that the query completed every single time, which would make our sites slow...

So, I'm calling it by design.

(Also [shouldiblamecaching.com](http://shouldiblamecaching.com))

Comment: There was definitely something going on when this question was asked though.  I did not even have a `Featured` tab on the front page.  It is back now, but it was gone all through yesterday.

Comment: Yeah, the occasional performance hiccup happens. That, or we checked in some poor code. :)

Comment: I still don't understand how it becomes "0" only?

Comment: An integer's default value is 0. If the query doesn't return the count in time, the default is used.

Comment: Why not keep the previous value then instead of setting it to 0?

Comment: @Stijn valid point. Design choice, and also how do you know programmatically whether or not 0 is valid? On a new or beta site 0 could very well be the truth.