# "featured" tab missing when current tab is "interesting"

Tags: bug, status-completed, homepage

When the "interesting" tab is selected, the "featured" tab is missing - or am I missing something? Choosing another tab, "hot" for example, shows the expected header with all tabs in place:

[image]

Code from Firebug's "Inspect element":

```
<div id="tabs">
<a class="youarehere" title="Questions that may be of interest to you based on your history and tag preference" href="?tab=interesting">interesting</a>
<a title="Questions with the most views, answers, and votes over the last few days" href="?tab=hot">hot</a>
<a title="Questions with the most views, answers, and votes this week" href="?tab=week">week</a>
<a title="Questions with the most views, answers, and votes this month" href="?tab=month">month</a>
</div>
```

[image]

Code from Firebug's "Inspect element":

```
<div id="tabs">
<a title="Questions that may be of interest to you based on your history and tag preference" href="?tab=interesting">interesting</a>
<a title="Questions with an active bounty" href="?tab=featured">
    <span class="bounty-indicator-tab">440</span>
    featured
</a>
<a class="youarehere" title="Questions with the most views, answers, and votes over the last few days" href="?tab=hot">hot</a>
<a title="Questions with the most views, answers, and votes this week" href="?tab=week">week</a>
<a title="Questions with the most views, answers, and votes this month" href="?tab=month">month</a>
</div>
```

Since not everyone is experiencing this problem (see [Stijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/247702/stijn)'s [comment below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272492/featured-tab-missing-when-current-tab-is-interesting?noredirect=1#comment99748_272492)), I'm using Firefox 32.0.3. I'll verify this at home, where I possibly have a different version.

There is one error shown in the Firebug console (I've translated it from Polish, so it may not be the exact error message that would be presented in English):

> Connection with wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/ was interrupted when loading the page.                 full.en...31a02f2 (line 1)
>
> ...er("message",n,!1),$.post("/users/login/global/request","",function(t){var n=e+"...

It pops out and disappears from the console, regardless of which tab I click.

---

I've tried clearing the whole cache, cookies, etc. After I was logged out it works allright:

[image]

Unfortunately, after logging in the problem occurs again.

---

On my other machine, on FF 32.0.1 it works fine.

Comment: Not able to reproduce here, but there's at least [one other person](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272061/featured-tab-at-0#comment97607_272061) who has the same issue.

Comment: Try running Firefox with [a clean profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue with how that bounty count was being initialized when a A/B split test was in progress.

A fix is being pushed out now.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not able to reproduce this - is this easily repeatable for you?  If so, can you open your developer tools and see if there's anything obviously wrong (js error messages, network errors, etc?)

Comment: Yes, it happens all the time. I'll try with Firebug, just a moment.

Comment: Added some details to the question post, let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: I am experiencing this as well. I am using Safari 7.1 on a Mac. I can't reproduce this on Firefox 32.0.3 on Mac however. There are no errors in the console or network errors whatsoever. The featured tab simply isn't in the HTML source when it arrives.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you did anything, but today it works :V

Comment: Still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Antony Feel free to edit my question if you have some more useful details.

Comment: I don't have anything to add. The featured tab reappears after I clear all the cookies and log out, but disappears as soon as I log in, just like what you experienced before. Maybe some A/B testing went wrong? I do remember this problem starting to occur during phase 2 of the recommended tab testing.

Comment: @Antony Have you tried [what Stijn have suggested](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272492/featured-tab-missing-when-current-tab-is-interesting/272730?noredirect=1#comment100662_272492)? I wanted to do it today, but cannot reproduce the problem anymore. Anyway, I've unaccepted this answer :)

Comment: Well, [I have this problem on Safari](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272492/featured-tab-missing-when-current-tab-is-interesting/272730?noredirect=1#comment100668_272497), not Firefox. I have tried private browsing instead, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Antony Could you confirm that it's working after [the fix](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272893/2642204)?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. I am the first person to upvote his answer.