# Confusing: Current tab not visible when on featured and there are no featured questions

Tags: bug, bounty

This may be as designed, but I rarely use the featured tab so I didn't understand what was happening.

From a [google search result](https://www.google.ca/search?q=netrw%20open%20http%20in%20browser) (link title: Newest 'netrw' Questions - Stack Overflow), I went to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netrw

I am logged in to Stack Overflow so it displayed the featured questions (I must have used the featured tab recently). There are no featured questions for netrw, so the page has no questions and doesn't show the featured tab:

[image]

It says I'm on the featured tab, but since the current tab is not visible it's not clear what that means. I can't even tell that 'newest' is a tab (it just looks like a link). It looks like I'm on the "Questions" tab -- that's the only thing visibly active.

The other disconnect is "You are on the Featured tab" and "no questions with an active bounty". I didn't realize that only questions with bounty are featured. (I figured the "hot" questions on the right might count as featured.)

If I use incognito, it displays the newest tab. Presumably, this is where google got its text result from and why it brought me to that page. I would expect to go to the same page that google indexed. Also, since switching tabs does not change the URL, so there's no user-visible difference between the two states (or way for search engines to link directly to newest).

Looking at [other tags with >0 featured questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim), the featured tab displays correctly.

## Summary

Bug: The featured tab is not displayed when there are no featured questions. Seems like it should always be displayed and show 0 questions.

Possible confusion reducing feature: When the referrer is a search engine, show newest regardless of user's last tab.

Possible confusion reducing feature: "Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab" could be a link to 'newest'.

Comment: Possibly related: [“featured” tab missing when current tab is “interesting”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272492/featured-tab-missing-when-current-tab-is-interesting)

Comment: I was just about to post this....

Comment: related : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274719/2333214